# Django create zip file and download/upload "correctly"

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Which parts of Django should handle file download, upload and manipulation functionality? "Where should this code live?"

I have a Django app. I want implement the following functionality in the admin interface.

Download Function:

1. Take some model objects and write them to a file (json, pickle, shelve, whatever)
2. Zip the file created in step 1, along with some image files
3. The user downloads the zip file and temp files are deleted

Upload Function:

1. User upload the file described above
2. The file is unzipped, the image files are written to the disk and new objects are created to load the data into the database

Which parts of the my Django app are the "correct" parts for me to implement this functionality into?

**Edit:**

To put it another way: "Where should this code live?"

**Edit:**

To clarify my question. In the extreme case, all of this could be written one `.py` file. For example in `views.py`. This would "work" but probably be "incorrect" from an MVC perspective. My is how to do this "correctly", rather than just how to get this working.

Comment: Not all! To answering this broad! Narrow down further what's the specific one you need to go further. Include your achievement in there...

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Show some snippets, that'd help the community understand your question in detail.